# changing the node version used by apache web server

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, webserver, node-modules

Hi here are few observations,
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYeT8.png)

I have a php program
`

```
<?php
$op=exec('node -v');
$op1=exec('which node');
echo "Node  version : $op";
echo "\n Node path : $op1";
echo "\nUser : ". get_current_user();
?>
```

`
when i run this program from my command line as ubuntu user

```
Node  version : v20.11.1
Node path : /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/bin/node
User : root
```

when i run this program from command line as root user

```
Node  version : v18.20.0
Node path : /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.0/bin/node
User : root
```

and when i run this file from browser

```
Node version : v10.19.0 
Node path : /usr/bin/node 
User : root
```

I want the node version used by apache web server also to be set to node 18 or node 20. How can i do that? as i want to use some node modules that are not compatible with node 10. How can i change node js version for apache web server to 18 or 20?

Comment: Your other users have a .nvm directory, where node is found.  The user which runs your httpd does not, so it uses the system node instance.  Setup your apache user like the other users you show here.  Or upgrade the version found under /usr/bin

Comment: It looks like when you login with root, the PATH variable is set to point to the .nvm version first, not the one under /usr/bin.  But when Apache starts it probably does not load the environment root has.  You could modifiy your envvars apache file to add the .nvm directory to your PATH.